# How can I quickly build muscle and slowly lose fat?

Tags: body-fat, muscle-mass

I suppose I'm your typical skinny fat. I don't have a lot of muscle, but I do have a bit of a gut.

My main goal is to bulk up, with a secondary goal of losing fat. Thus, I'm aiming to build muscle quickly, and I'm willing to trim my gut more slowly as a tradeoff. What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

### Can I lose fat and build muscle at the same time?

The ability to gain muscle while losing fat is dependent on the relationship between your fatness and muscularity. An overly-fat and under-trained person will be able to achieve simultaneous fat loss and muscle gain. A very lean person near his/her limit for muscle growth will not. As one moves away from the overly-fat, under-trained status towards a leaner, more muscular body this ability is diminished. At some point, the vast majority of people will see better/quicker results by choosing to do one or the other (gain muscle, lose fat - often referred to as 'bulking' and 'cutting', respectively) at a time. For a highly general rule of thumb: if you have been training effectively for a year or more, you're better off with a bulk/cut cycle. [See Lyle McDonald's Adding Muscle While Losing Fat - Q&A for more discussion.](http://www.bodyrecomposition.com/fat-loss/adding-muscle-while-losing-fat-qa.html)

A [2011 paper](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/51113664_Effect_of_two_different_weight-loss_rates_on_body_composition_and_strength_and_power-related_performance_in_elite_athletes?ev=pub_srch_pub) suggests a weekly rate of body-weight loss of 0.7% can permit muscle gain in both men and women while losing fat mass. Women were also able to increase muscle while losing fat at a weekly rate of body-weight loss of 1.0-1.4%. Men, however, lost muscle mass at this increased rate.

In real terms, 0.7% body-weight loss was achieved via a daily deficit of 3.2 calories per lb of total bodyweight (or 7 calories per kg of total bodyweight). At this rate, your **goal calorie intake = [TDEE](http://www.reddit.com/r/Fitness/wiki/getting_started#wiki_fixing_your_diet) - [BWlb x 3.2kcal] (or TDEE - [BWkg x 7kcal])**. This is a good place to start. The 1.0-1.4% range works out to a daily deficit of 4.5-6.4 calories per lb of total bodyweight (or 10-14 calories per kg of total bodyweight).

Answer (score -3):

That depends on your money balance.  If you have money go to the gym train hard and eat **clean** , nutrition is everything But if you don't try some street workout like way. Your body is in your kitchen not in the gym. I would recommend you to start calisthenics or freeletics. Watch those on youtube to get motivated and keep trying to reach your goal. All you need is a bar . I DO NOT recommend crossfit.  Don't try crossfit it is really bad .. at least that's My opinion.  You might have seen those guys doing incredible handstand moves on YouTube or Facebook.  With Calisthenics you can achieve things like: front lever 
Back lever , planche , muscle up and much more.  I mention once again "eat clean"

> Never give up

Comment: Doesn't really address the question and is rather biased. Also "clean" eating is rather subjective.